# Convergence of series in p-adic field or non-archimedian field

Tags: sequences-and-series, p-adic-number-theory

**Field of $p$-adic numbers:**

> Show that  if $ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \ $ converges , then $ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n^2 \ $ converges in p-adic field.

**Answer:**

At first remember that this is a Non-Archimedian field.

So the **comparison test** may be different.

That is why I am getting no way to prove it because

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \ $ converges means $ \ a_n \to 0 \ $

Thus $ \ a_n \geq a_n^2 \ $

By comparison test,

$ \sum_{0}^{\infty} a_n \geq \sum_{0}^{\infty} a_n^2 \ $ converges.

But here in Non-archimedian field or p-adic field the comparison test is applicable or not I don't know.

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a perfectly valid $p$-adic comparison test, as uninteresting as it may be.

Namely, if $\sum a_n$ is convergent and for each $n$, $|b_n|\le|a_n|$, then $\sum b_n$ is also convergent.

But as @Watson has pointed out, if $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then $|a_n|\to0$, and thus under the hypotheses on $\{b_n\}$, you get $|b_n|\to0$, so that automatically $\sum b_n$ will be convergent.

Answer (score 4):

In a non-archimedean space, we have the wonderful property that $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n$ converges as soon as $a_n \to 0$.
Since $a_n \to 0$ implies that $a_n^2 \to 0$, you can conclude that $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n^2$ converges.

Comment: Yes sir. That is I know. But I want to know whether comparison test is applicable in Non-archimedian field as I mentioned . Can you clear my confusion? Actually I want to prove in another way. Thanks

Comment: @yourmath : comparison test doesn't make sense in general since $\Bbb Q_p$ is not an ordered field (for $p>2$ you have $p-1>1$ roots of unity).

Comment: Is not there $ \ p-adic \ $ order?

Comment: @yourmath : no, there is no total order $\leq$ such that $(\Bbb Q_p, \leq)$ is an ordered field. Comparison test is not suitable, then.

Comment: Ok , many thanks to you

Comment: @yourmath : see for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375734/how-to-show-that-mathbbq-p-cannot-be-ordered).

Comment: That means p-adic field is an example of Non-Archimedian Non-ordered  field. Is it true?

Comment: @yourmath : yes, exactly.

Comment: We know p-adic field is an Non-archimedian field. Because there is a p-adic absolute value or Non-Archimedian absolute value. My question is why the p-adic absolute value is called Non-archimedian? I saw some the reason that $ |n|_p <1 \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z} \ $ . But how we get $ \ |n|_p<1 \ $ in p-adic field?

Comment: @yourmath : because $|n|_p = p^{-v_p(n)}$ and $v_p(n) \geq 0$, you get $|n|_p \leq 1$ for any integer $n \in \Bbb Z$ (but not $|n|_p < 1$) — here $v_p(n)$ is the $p$-adic valuation, which counts the multiplicity of the prime factor $p$ in $n$.